# personalize the view related to one action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Is there a way to personalize the view related to only one action?

For instance I have the action `campaigns#index` and I want index.html.erb only to have an image background, because all the csss are included in one file how can I work out this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
<% if (params[:action] == "index") %>
  ...your code here, setting class="special-background"
<% else %> 
  ...alternate code here, not setting the class
<% end %>
```

Then all you need to so is set the css for that class to show your background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selectors to specify a background for just the index page. For instance, if you wanted to have a background on just the content of the index page, you could have your view look something like:

```
<div id='campaigns-index'>
  <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

And then in your css do something to the effect of:

```
div#campaigns-index {
  background-image: ...
}
```

I suggest you read up on css selectors (particularly ids). Here's a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).